# Ember app not able to bind a delayed object

Tags: ember.js

I have an Ember.js application using ember-auth.

```
Auth.on("signInSuccess", function() {
  App.currentUser = App.User.find(Auth.currentUserId);
});
```

I also have a controller (see **App.currentUser**):

```
App.CustomersIndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  currentUserBinding: 'App.currentUser'

  customers: null,

  loadCustomers: (function() {
    var company = this.get('currentUser').get('company');
    return this.set('customers', company.get('customers'));
  }).observes('currentUser.company')
});
```

**The problem:**

The binding do not work, since "App.currentUser" is null. The controller initialize before the "signInSuccess" event.

The "customers" should have the currentUser's company customers as default. The controller also have logic (removed from the shown code), so "customers" can be set to another array by the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will probably have to use `set` method to properly notify observers.

```
App.set('currentUser', App.User.find(Auth.currentUserId));
```

Comment: Auth.currentUserId is null when the controller is initialized, since the controller's route is the first to be visited.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to reply. Your help is much appreciated and it works perfect. I guess my question was more a pattern question, but maybe I just have to get used to all those setters and getters.

Comment: From design point of view you could do this `customersBinding: 'currentUser.company.customers'`